# How to go to specific folder in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

From Eclipse, how to go to the specific folder? I mean in windows, how to open a command line which corresponding to the folder or direct open the file explorer to open the corresponding folder?

Answer (score 6):

You have to create an external tool with location `${env_var:SystemRoot}\explorer.exe` (or cmd.exe) and arguments `/select,${resource_loc}` . Any selected file or directory can now be shown in the windows explorer.

### Create an External tool

Go into the external tool configuration (you can find it into the corresponding toolbar icon) :

[image]

Then you can create your own external tool :

[image: External Tool Creation]

1. Create a new Program (select Program in the tree)
2. Name it shell
3. Set the location to `${env_var:SystemRoot}\explorer.exe`
4. Set the arguments to `/select,${resource_loc}`
5. Run the external tool

Once created you can run the external tool from the context menu or from the toolbar ...

Answer (score 4):

I have been using an Eclipse plugin called **[PathTools](http://code.google.com/p/pathtools/)** for sometime now, and am happy with it.

It adds a number of buttons to the Eclipse toolbar which allow you to :

1. Directly open a cmd prompt at the selected folder.
2. Open an Explorer window for the selected folder.

Update site : http://pathtools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PathToolsUpdateSite/site.xml

### Sample screenshots

#### Installing the `Path Tools Feature`

I chose to install only the `Path Tools Feature` 
[image]

#### Opening a terminal

Opening a terminal directly at the Folder Path :
[image]

(The above snapshot is that for OSX but works in Windows as well)

#### Opening Explorer

Opening a folder directly in Explorer/Finder :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Great simple plugin for this:
http://basti1302.github.com/startexplorer/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

2019 update (no plugins required):

Right click the desired folder in the Project Explorer, go to Show In, choose either Terminal or System Explorer. See below screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of menu]

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file (in left pane).. then use Win Goodies -> Open file in Explorer